# How to ensure my database design is scalable?

Tags: database-design, cakephp, relational-database

I have two Models - Users and Restaurants. They can set tweets like status messages and can have replies. I have the following setup and need your help to optimise the design.

```
users(id, name, ......)
restaurants(id, name.....)
modules(id, name)  [this table stores the modules - (1,user) and (2,restaurant)
```

My message table

```
status_messages(id, pid, message, time, module_id, moduleID)

id - Uid, primary key
pid - self ID or parent ID - for accomodating the replies in to the same table.
message - the status message is stored here
time - the time the status message was set
module_id - refers to the module its pointing - Users or Restaurants
moduleID - the actual foreign key
```

Is this the right way to go about ?

The scale of the application: it would be an open application worldwide, so will one table scale to all those restaurants and users.

I want to have a similar models for reviews which will cater to Restaurants, Dishes, Events, Buffet on a single table. Would it be overkill?

Comment: i just call Users and Restaurants modules.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish, but having two module IDs in your status_messages table looks odd. Plus, why is there no relationship with the users table?

Comment: Indeed, your question is not clear. As I know the convention is to name the field `parent_id` instead of `pid`.

Comment: module_id = referes the records is  for Users or Restaurants ( 1 = users, 2 = restaurants ) ModuleID = the foreign key to reference the id from the refered module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this design should be fine,  you would want to place some kind of index on the status_messages.module_id  column  so that selects on the table can be filtered by user/restaurant.

Normally on the server side you would create two classes for the status message table

1 class  UserMessages 
2nd class RestaurantMessages

and use some sort of ORM tool to define the module_id as the decriminator column. So in the database its in one table to maximize reuse.  But on the application it has two different names (logical names).   Not sure how this works in PHP.

Comment: Also maybe you should consider renaming Module to  ParentTable so other people can understand your naming better.

Comment: thanks.   yes i guess people are getting confused. with the naming convention :D